# which algorithm used by sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit for clustering into n_splits

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering

which algorithm is used by sklearn class **StratifiedShuffleSplit** for clustering/stratification into n_split. dendrogram looks evident but can anyone suggest any reference.

class sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=None, train_size=None, random_state=None)